# i keep getting Undefined array key

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return the data of the database query then access it as an array in the blade file, but i keep getting this error:Undefined array key "cover_img".

my controller

```
$id=request()->segment(count(request()->segments()));

$userdata=DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')->where('id',$id)->get();

if($id!=auth()->id()) {
    return view('show-prof')->with(compact('userdata'));
} else {
    return view('profile');
}
```

my blade file

```
<div class="container">
    @if($userdata['cover_img']!=null)
        <img src="{{url('/images/user_cover_img/'.$userdata['cover_img'])}}" id="cover">
    @else
        <img src="/images/user_cover_img/cover_default.png" id="cover">
    @endif
</div>
```

I tested if the array is being returned by typing

```
<p>{{$userdata}}</p>
```

and the output was

[{"id":1,"first_name":"mohamad","last_name":"abedelhady","profile_img":null,"cover_img":null}]
I also tried dd($userdata)and the output was:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#377 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1255 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"first_name": "mohamad"
      +"last_name": "abedelhady"
      +"profile_img": null
      +"cover_img": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `{{userdata}}` would be `{{$userdata}}`. Have you tried `dd($userdata)` to see if it's an array or an object? Have you tried `$userdata->cover_img`?

Comment: does cover_img exist as a column on your users table and does it have data on the row you're looking at? also it's not an array

Comment: @brombeer i tryied $userdata->cover_img and it gave me this error Property [cover_img] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: I tried dd($userdata) and the output was: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#377 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1255 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"first_name": "mohamad"
      +"last_name": "abedelhady"
      +"profile_img": null
      +"cover_img": null
    }
  ]
}

Comment: `$userdata=DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')->where('id',$id)->get()->toArray();` will give you an array instead of object containg array, then iterate it in the Blade to render each element (even if single)

Comment: First of all it's an object, not an array. Second, you are getting your data with an ->get() function, meaning you will receive multiple rows. So you need to foreach through your data. But I think you need to replace your ->get() with a ->first(), and then using $userdata->cover_img. That should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query gives you an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object (a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction)) that contains anonymous objects (stdClass):

```php
// This 
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->where('id',$id)->get();
```

I think you only want to get the user by id, pls do this.

```php
$user = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->where('id',$id)->first();

// Or
$user = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->whereKey($id)->first();
```

Because the `$user` is an anonymous object, you got to access the attributes this way:

```php
$user->cover_img;
```

Alternatively, if you have a `User` model, you can simply do this.

```php
$user = User::find($id);

// Then both are gonna work, but I recommend using the former.
$user->cover_img;
$user['cover_img'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's looks at your Eloquent Quer here:

```
$userdata=DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->where('id',$id)->get();
```

here get() method returns an array of user records. So instead of

```
$userdata['cover_img']!=null
```

You need to access cover_img from the first element of the array. Like this:

```
$userdata[0]['cover_img']!=null
```

It seems you are only dealing with a single record and should use the `first()` method to only get the single object and then your code should work

```
$userdata=DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->where('id',$id)->first();
```

**Remember**: The first() method will return only one record, while the get() method will return an array of records that you can loop over.